# How can I get Libre Office to accept pasted text?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, pdf-reader

I am trying to paste some information copied from a PDF document into an Open Office document (Libre Office 5.0.4.2), but instead of pasting the information that is in the clipboard to the .odt file, it pastes the search item I used to search the PDF file.

Specifically, after searching the PDF file for "Black Elk" I copy this from the PDF file to the clipboard:

```
in 1932, Black Elk, who worked with Cody in this Wild West show, recalled about Wounded Knee:
Ididnotknowthenhowmuchwasended.WhenIlookbacknowfromthishighhill ofmyoldage,Icanstillseethebutcheredwomenandchildrenlyingheapedandscattered all along the crooked gulch as plain as when I saw them with eyes still young. And I can see that something else died there in the bloody mud, and was buried in the blizzard. A people’s dream died there. It was a beautiful dream.
```

...but when I do a paste into the .odt file, it pastes the text "Black Elk" rather than the text above.

This happens whether I select the text in the PDF file, right-click, and select "Copy" or select Ctrl+C on my keyboard.

I know the text shown above (admittedly malformed, with missing spaces galore) is in the clipboard, because I can paste it elsewhere, such as into a Notepad (.txt) file.

This is the process I use, which was working until this particular passage of text:

```
Enter a search phrase using the "Find on Page" feature (PDF file is opened in the Edge browser - NOTE: It also fails in the same way using Chrome)

Move to the location where the phrase is found

Select the desired text

Right-click the "Copy" context menu item or Ctrl+C

In the .odt file, select the spot where I want to insert the text, and either select Ctrl+V or Edit > Paste
```

It has worked previously, but now it always pastes the search phrase rather than the selected/copied-to-the-clipboard phrase.

Why, and what can I do to get it to work again?

### UPDATE

It is definitely a problem with Libre Office, because I downloaded Adobe Touch Reader, and copied and pasted from there with the same result; I am using the latest version of Libre Office.

### UPDATE 2

I've determined when it happens, but don't know why it would:

When I copy some text from the .odt document into the browser's "Find on page" box, that text becomes the only thing that can thereafter be pasted back into the .odt document. If I type the text in instead, the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down Libre Office and restarting it solved it. I had previously tried closing and reopening the document, but that made no difference.